# Sigma algebra of the set of continuous functions

Tags: general-topology, measure-theory

In some reading I saw:

> Let $T$ be an index subset of $\mathbb{R}$. Denote $C$ as the set of continuous functions from $T\to \mathbb{R}$. Then $\mathcal{C}:=\sigma(C)$ is the same as the Borel sigma-algebra generated by the topology of uniform convergence on compact sets.

May I ask where I can see more discussion about this?

Comment: What is $\sigma(C)$ by definition?

Comment: @Shunan Sheng Could you please give a reference for this statement ?

Comment: @Medo It is from a lecture note, on page 5 http://people.math.gatech.edu/~mdamron6/teaching/Fall_2019/Math_7244/notes/Math_7244_week_4.pdf

Comment: $\sigma(C)$ is the smallest sigma-algebra such that all elements in $C$ are measurable